# Nested routes in Ember JS and Ember Rails

Tags: ember.js, ember-rails

Can someone explain in layman's terms the way nested outlets work in ember templates?

In particular trying understand this from the docs:
http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/

> "The immediate parent route did not render into the main outlet ..."
>
> This means that the current route tried to render into the parent
>   route's template, but the parent route didn't render a template, or,
>   if it did, that the template which the parent route provided did not
>   render into the main template (i.e., a default {{outlet}}).

More specifically I am trying understand how to create a nested view hierarchy in my app. 
It is three layers deep of collections. I want to create a series of collapsible nested views, based on the contents of the collections. The data structure could be tree like.

Libraries -> each Library has many Books -> each Book has many Pages

Looking for an illustrative jsbin or code sample that demonstrates the nested template structure in practice.

Imagine a router that looks like this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {

    this.resource('libraries', function() {
        this.route('new');

        this.resource('library', {path: ':library_id'}, function() {

            this.resource('books', function() {
                this.route('new');
                this.resource('book', {path: ':book_id'}, function() {

                    this.resource('pages', function() {
                        this.route('new');
                        this.resource('page', {path: ':page_id'}, function() {

                        }); // Page
                    }); // Pages

                }); // Book
            }); // Books

        }); // Library
    }); // Libraries

}); // map
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general most templating languages provide some way to wrap the `target` content of a page into a main layout. This allows separation of the common page layout into another file and the smaller target template in a different file.

There have been a few iterations of this in Ember, currently this functionality is provided by the `{{outlet}}` helper. Outlets are Ember's way to `yield` into a layout.

The area where `outlet` diverges significantly from `yield` is nesting. Yielding on server-side is much simpler. You only need to mark areas of a template to yield into and then call to yield a block of content into that designated target.

However when the rendering of content is switched to client-side javascript, only parts of a page are updated on demand. You can no longer simply `yield` directly into markers. You need a smarter `yield` ie:- `outlet`.

There are 2 sides to an `{{outlet}}`.

1. A marker that indicates where you want to yield. This is the `{{outlet}}` helper.
2. Code that renders a template into this outlet. This is the `render` method used inside the `renderTemplate` hook.

By default an `{{outlet}}` does not need a name. This makes it the default outlet for that template. There can be many such outlets in a template and they can be specified by giving it a name. For eg:-

```
{{outlet 'sidebar'}}
{{outlet 'nav'}}
```

This declares 2 outlets named 'sidebar' and 'nav'. You can now render other templates into these outlets.

Default outlets are used when rendering without an explicit outlet name. For named outlets the rendering is done by calling `render` in a `renderTemplate` hook of a `Route`.
You do this by specifying an `outlet` option in a hash passed to the `render` method as options.

```
renderTemplate() {
    this.render('recentPosts', { outlet: 'sidebar' });
}
```

Here, the template `recentPosts` will be rendered into an outlet named 'sidebar' inside its parent template.

When routes are nested inside other nested routes they will render into the nearest parent outlet. If the parent resource doesn't have a default outlet then it's parent is used, and so on until the `application` template is reached.

When you declare a `resource` with `this.resource('posts');` in the `Router`, you are indicating a few things based on convention.

1. Render the `posts` route with the layout template `posts`.
2. Optionally, render the implicit `posts.index` route with the template `posts/index`.

The `posts` template contains layout common to all posts and it's sub resources. At the bare minimum it must contain at least a default outlet like, `{{outlet}}`.

Without this `{{outlet}}` child routes will not have an immediate parent outlet to render into. They will then render in that parent's parent or ultimately the `application` template's outlet. When this happens you will see the `"The immediate parent route did not render into the main outlet ..."` warning. Check the location of your `outlets` when this happens.

The `posts.index` is an implicit route given to all resources that have nested routes. In other words if your resource has nested routes, you don't need to explicitly declare a nested, `this.route('index`)`.

This `index` route can display the content of that resource. For instance, for `posts.index`, You can display a list of all `posts`. One secondary caveat with this implicit route is that the model is on the parent `posts` route. You have to use the `needs` api to get at this model in the `PostsIndexController`.

```
needs: ['posts'],
contentBinding: 'controller.posts'
```

Further, this `posts.index` route is optional. You can place the UI from `posts/index` used to display a list of posts, directly into the `posts` template itself. However this means any child resource will also render with the list of posts, along side the outlet in `posts`. The decision whether to use an explicit index route or not depends on the UI that needs to be displayed.

Sitting above all other templates is the `application` template. It must have an `outlet` for nested resources to render in, and will typically house the layout common to the page. If you don't specify an application template a default template will be used. This generated template is equivalent to `{{outlet}}`, ie:- a template with just a default outlet.

Consider the following routes.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('posts', function() {
      this.route('new')
      this.resource('post', {path: ':post_id'}, function() {
        this.resource('comments', function() {
          this.route('new');
        });
      });
    });
});
```

Here, `posts.new` will be rendered into `posts` which will be rendered inside `posts`, which will be rendered into the `application` template's default outlet. The rest of the templates used are listed below.

```
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Route                     | Templates used (default outlets)                       |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| posts.index               | posts.index > posts > application                      |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| posts.new                 | posts.new > posts > application                        |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| posts.post.index          | post.index > post > posts > application                |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| posts.post.new            | post.new > post > posts > application                  |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| posts.post.comments.index | comments.index > comments > post > posts > application |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| posts.post.comments.new   | comments.new > comments > post > posts > application   |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

This default template hierarchy can be changed by specifying an `into` option to the `render` method.

```
renderTemplate: function() {
  this.render('posts', { into: 'sidebar' })
}
```

Here the `posts` template will render into the default outlet of the `sidebar` template.

That's about it. `Outlet` is another ember concept that uses a good deal of convention over configuration. The defaults are quite good, at the same time easy to customize.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed overview Darshan. The Route --> Templates tables helps clarify somethings. I will have read this couple more time before I fully grok it. I just need to keep things straight in my mind when it comes to the nesting behavior.

Comment: where did u define the Route 'posts.post.new'?

Comment: @Darshan could you also look at my question that also addresses router behavior for emberjs? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17780344/nested-routing-behavior-for-ember-js