# Emberjs controller needs with Binding

Tags: binding, ember.js, controllers

I have nested resources:

```
    this.resource('foo', {path: '/foo/:foo_id'}, function() {
        this.route('makesomethingwithfoo');

        this.resource('bar', {path: 'bar/:bar_id'}, function() {
            this.route('makesomethingwithbar');
```

I want to use some properties from the model `foo` in, while I'm in `#/foo/321421/bar/231421`. 
My `BarIndexController` looks like this:

```
   ... = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs:'fooIndex',
    //myBinding: 'controllers.fooIndex',
    ....});
```

In my template if I use `controllers.fooIndex.desiredProperty` I can access the property of model `foo`. I wanted to use `myBinding` in order to spare writing a few characters more ( `controllers.fooIndex`). I think I did everything right, at least it seems right according to the [documentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/). I get this error:

```
     Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Cannot delegate set('my', <(subclass of 
     Ember.ObjectController):ember238>) to the 'content' property of object proxy
     <(subclass of Ember.ObjectController):ember249>: its 'content' is undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `controller` that has the model is `foo`. The `fooIndex` route is an implicit nested route of the `foo` route, and hence has a controller of it's own. The nested `FooIndexController` also needs to lookup the model on it's parent routes as needed.

In this case your `bar` route needs to use `foo` instead of `fooIndex` in the needs declaration.

```
needs:'foo',
fooBinding: 'controllers.foo'
```

The `fooBinding` is optional. It shortens the lookup to `this.get('foo')`. You might also want to refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662791/nested-routes-in-ember-js-and-ember-rails/17674040#17674040) to help clarify nested resources in Ember.